# send data (text lines) from computer to my android application with usb cable

Tags: android

I am trying to send data(text lines) from computer application to my android phone application via the usb cable? is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

can try only with android 3.1 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/package-summary.html